# How can I make the Visual Studio 2008 to display Server Controls in the Toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm developing an ASP.Net webapp, I've HTML controls and Server controls in my VS2008 Toolbox originally. However, the Server controls section was disappeared suddenly. How can I make them to be visible in the Toolbox?

Thank you!

BRs,
William Choi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Toolbox and add references to the controls you need.

Comment: Do you mean I have to add each control manually? or is there a way to add a group of references of .Net Server Controls?

Comment: You can do that. Or, you can also right click on the Toolbox and select Reset toolbox.